# Flutter app on my iPhone without Apple Store

Tags: iphone, flutter, app-store

Good evening, I was wandering if there is the possibility to fully download (not just debug) an app made by me with Flutter on my own iPhone without passing through the App Store and without the developer account of Apple. Thanks in advance!

Edit: If I develop the app with React Native instead of Flutter is the same or in that case can I download it?

Comment: Is it enough for you to just install the Release version of your app on your device, or do you want to publish the app somewhere so the app could be downloaded?

Comment: You can't install iOS app in device without apple development account.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, you can't do that because you have to need developer account to install the app on your phone. That's iOS requirements, but you can create free amount then you create free certificate just one week.

https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/47843

Comment: This means that the app on my iPhone after one week won't work?

Comment: actually doesn't run again your phone. You have to renew your certificate every week.

Answer (score 0):

To install a Flutter app on an iOS device you need to either generate an IPA file or publish your application in the App Store. To be able to achieve that you need two things :

1. A MacOS machine with XCode
2. An Apple developer account

For 1 there are solutions. If you do not own a Mac you can use services like [odevio](https://odevio.com/) to configure and build your app. It's pretty easy to use.

For 2, you do not really have a choice. To be able to install an app on a physical device you have to add the device UDID in your developer account. Otherwise the IPA will not be installed.

Comment: Is not there a conflict with this response and the response in this link? https://stackoverflow.com/a/71796514/14269222

Comment: Not really, no. 

"It is important to note that the app will only work for one week, so if OP wants his app to work for more than a week, the answer to his question is no, it is not possible. – 
Christian Brinch
 Sep 20 at 5:59"